# When I call EclipseLink merge why does it do a select query first when I've already requested the object via it?

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

When I call EclipseLink merge why does it do a select query first?

Using the sql statement logging I see it always does a select before the update.

I would have through due to the L2 cache it wouldn't need to do thye select first.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the object is in the cache it will not issue a select.  Either you object is not in the shared cache, or is invalid.

If still having problems include your code and config.